# Username that created the Virtual Machine in Azure using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, virtual-machine, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

I want to know if there is a way to get the username which created the Virtual Machine on Azure. I can look for the usernames that initiated the Virtual Machine using the **Activity Log** but there the logs are retained only for 90 days.
So if I want to access this data for VMs created before 90 days from today, I can't look for it.

Is there any way to get such details using `MonitorManagementClient` or any other class irrespective of their last accessed date?

Answer (score 0):

By default records are only [stored for 90 days](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log#send-to--azure-storage). You can't go back further because those records no longer exist. If you would like them stored longer, go into the [diagnostic settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/diagnostic-settings) in Azure Monitor and have them streamed to Azure Storage or Log Analytics as well as Azure Monitor. Keep in mind that you do have to pay for the data in storage. That won't help with the older data, but it will let you retain the data longer from here on.

[image]

Comment: what about the records within 90 days? How can I retrieve that data?

Comment: MonitorManagementClient is correct. Within that you want to use the ActivityLogsOperations class. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-monitor/azure.mgmt.monitor.v2015_04_01.operations.activitylogsoperations?view=azure-python